# Finding the strongly connected components in a Di-Graph in one DFS

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

By now, I have used the following algorithm for finding the strongly connected components of a graph.

1. call DFS(G) to compute the finishing time f[v] for every vertex v, sort the vertices of G in decreasing order of their finishing time;
2. compute the transpose GT of G;
3. Perform another DFS on G, this time in the main for-loop we go through the vertices of G
   in the decreasing order of f[v];
4. output the vertices of each tree in the DFS forest (formed by the second DFS) as a separate
   strongly connected component.

.

But I was wondering if it is possible to find all the strongly connected components in **only one DFS.**

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out, Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena. It calculates SCC in one DFS. It's based on the concept of oldest reachable vertex.

Initialize each vertex's reachable vertex and SCComponent# to itself in the beginning.

```
low[i] = i;
scc[i] = -1;
```

Do a DFS on the digraph, you are interested only in back edges and cross edges because these two edges will tell you if you've encountered a back edge and entering 1 component from another.

```
  int edge_classification(int x, int y)
  {
    if (parent[y] == x) return(TREE);
    if (discovered[y] && !processed[y]) return(BACK);
    if (processed[y] && (entry_time[y]>entry_time[x])) return(FORWARD);
    if (processed[y] && (entry_time[y]<entry_time[x])) return(CROSS);
     printf("Warning: unclassified edge (%d,%d)\n",x,y);
  }
```

So when you encounter these edges, you set reachable vertex[] recursively, based on the entry times.
    if (class == BACK) {
                if (entry_time[y] < entry_time[ low[x] ] )
                low[x] = y;
    }

```
if (class == CROSS) 
{
            if (scc[y] == -1)  /* component not yet assigned */
                    if (entry_time[y] < entry_time[ low[x] ] )
                            low[x] = y;
}
```

A new strongly connected component is found whenever the lowest reachable vertex from vertex 'v' is itself (loop can say, a->b->c->a, lowest reachable vertex of a is a).

```
process_vertex_early(int v)
{
    push(&active,v);
}
```

After DFS for a vertex is complete (DFS for it's neighbors would have been completed too), check the lowest reachable vertex for it:

```
if (low[v] == v) 
{     /* edge (parent[v],v) cuts off scc */
          pop_component(v);
}

if (entry_time[low[v]] < entry_time[low[parent[v]]])
          low[parent[v]] = low[v];
```

pop_component(...) just pops from the stack until this component is found. If a->b->c->a is scanned the stack will have a(bottom)->b->c(top).. pop until vertex 'a' is seen. You get an SCC for 'a'..and similarly you get all connected components in one DFS.

Comment: 1071840 can u give me the link from where u read this material. I would like to go through complete topic as it has said some new things here.

Comment: http://sist.sysu.edu.cn/~isslxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Wikipedia page for [Strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component):

> Kosaraju's algorithm, Tarjan's algorithm and the path-based strong
>   component algorithm all efficiently compute the strongly connected
>   components of a directed graph, but Tarjan's and the path-based
>   algorithm are favoured in practice since they require **only one
>   depth-first search** rather than two.

I think this quite answers your question :)